# Using ng-class to change glyphicons sorting a table

Tags: angularjs, sorting, glyphicons, ng-class

I have been having trouble getting `ng-class` to work as intended. I have a table which can be sorted in descending and ascending order by clicking on the `glyphicon-chevron-down`. However this is where the issue lies.

I am trying to implement `ng-class` into all the sortable headers to be able to change the `glyphicon-chevron-down` to `glyphicon-chevron-up` when it is in ascending order and vice-versa.

The second part of the problem is the way it changes. When you click on a header it will sort in descending first and then the next click should show it in ascending with the `glyphicon-chevron-up` unless it is the default sorted header. In which case it should switch from descending (default state) to ascending.

Below is a plnkr with an example of the table in question. If someone can assist me in making this changes it would be appreciated.

http://plnkr.co/edit/LrnPj1nx4sdQD8F9ctKB?p=preview

Comment: Instead of prepending a `-` to your `orderProperty` you can pass `true`/`false` as a second argument to the `orderBy` filter. If you put this boolean into a scope attribute you can use it inside the `ng-class` to change the icon accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can verify on the `orderProperty` and use that in your `ng-class` condition to set `glyphicon-chevron-down` or `glyphicon-chevron-up`

```
<th>D<span id="tbl3" ng-click="setOrderProperty('d')" class="glyphicon pull-right" ng-class="{ 'glyphicon-chevron-down': orderProperty != 'd', 'glyphicon-chevron-up' : orderProperty == 'd' }"></span></th>
```

An example can be found here: http://plnkr.co/edit/3h4O7vQr8y4js4hj1otv

Comment: That's clever, I never thought of doing it that way. Simple and effective. Much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I do believe I just wrote this question incorrectly and I only noticed after looking at it again. In fact it's actually almost backwards. Instead of it `glyphicon-chevron-up` referring to ascending it should be the `glyphicon-chevron-down`. It also means that there is likely a need to record the state somehow? 


It would be because the glyphicon should be by default `glyphicon-chevron-down` and still be `glyphicon-chevron-down` when clicked because it is sorting in an ascending order.

It got a bit more complex, what modifications would be required as I can't just reverse the `!=` and `==`.